# Update grid with lookup in D365FO

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have a form with the datasource SalesTable in D365FO, I have a lookup field showing the SalesId and I want to show the information of the SalesTable in the grid based on what is selected in the lookup. Does anyone have the solution? I have read a lot of blogs but with no information about what I'm looking.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to add links to some of the blogs you read and explain why they did not work for you? Also, if you have some code that you could share, please do, it will increase your chances of receiving an answer.

Comment: Every one of the blogs says about how to do the lookup, but no one says something about how to put the information in the grid.

Comment: One way would be to use the `lookup` method to select a value, then use the `modified` method to update other grid fields based on te selected value. There are some serious caveats with this approach though... Have you considered display methods? What are your business requirements?

Comment: And how can I do this? In the OnModified method I can't use the this.valueStr(). I already try with the AutoDeclaration (Yes) and still with no result....